# Check whether sentence contains certain words

Tags: java, arrays, string, if-statement, contains

I have a sentence like:

```
I`ve got a Pc
```

And a set of words:

```
Hello
world
Pc
dog
```

How can I check whether the sentence contains any of those words? In this example I would have a match with `Pc`.

Here is what I got so far:

```
public class SentenceWordExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "I`ve got a Pc";
        String[] words = { "Hello", "world", "Pc", "dog" };

       // I know this does not work, but how to continue from here?
       if (line.contains(words) {
            System.out.println("Match!");
       } else {
            System.out.println("No match!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You would simply iterate all elements in your array and use `line.contains(arrayElement)`. If any matches, you have a match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd stream the array, and then check if the string contains any of its elements:

```java
if (Arrays.stream(stringArray).anyMatch(s -> line.contains(s)) {
    // Do something...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But I still have a question : The variable (s) is a String, right ? Because i want, that my code returns the place of the contained word from the array. If s would be a Integer it would be easy

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using a regex approach here, with an alternation:

```
String line = "I`ve got a Pc";
String[] array = new String[2];
array[0] = "Example sentence";
array[1] = "Pc";
List<String> terms = Arrays.asList(array).stream()
    .map(x -> Pattern.quote(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
String regex = ".*\\b(?:" + String.join("|", terms) + ")\\b.*";
if (line.matches(regex)) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

The exact regex which the above snippet generates is:

```
.*\b(?:Example sentence|Pc)\b.*
```

That is, we form an alternation containing all keyword terms for which we want to search in the input string.  Then, we use that regex with `String#matches`.

Comment: Note that this only works because the array elements contain no metacharacters. You could escape them with `Pattern::quote` if required.